# Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA + Sybase: No keys were automatically generated Sybase IDENTITY column

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, sybase

I am migrating one legacy application to a newer Apache Camel Spring Boot application where I am using Spring Data JPA to interact with Sybase database.

Legacy application uses older technologies versions like `Spring 3.x, Hibernate 3.x, jconn3` etc.

All the Tables in the Sybase DB have primary key defined as `IDENTITY` column.

Legacy application uses following to define identity columns and relation between `Block` and `Allocation` entity (`many-to-one bidirectional`):

**Block.hbm.xml**

```
<id name="blockPk" type="java.lang.Long">
    <column name="block_pk"/>
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>

<set name="allocations" inverse="true" cascade="all,delete-orphan" table="allocations" order-by="allocation_pk asc" fetch="select">
    <key>
       <column name="block_pk" not-null="true"/>
    </key>
<one-to-many class="Allocation"/>
</set>
```

**Allocation.hbm.xml**

```
<id name="allocationPk" type="java.lang.Long">
    <column name="allocation_pk"/>
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>

<many-to-one name="block" class="Block" type="select">
    <column name="block_pk" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
```

In new application I am doing something like this:

**Block.java**

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "block_pk")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long blockPk;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "block", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("allocationPk")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Allocation> allocations;
```

**Allocation.java**

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "allocation_pk")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long allocationPk;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "block_pk", nullable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Block block;
```

**Repositories**

```
@Repository
public interface BlockRepository extends JpaRepository<Block, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface AllocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Allocation, Long> {
}
```

**DbStore.java**

```
@Component
public class DbStore {
    @Autowired
    private BlockRepository blockRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AllocationRepository allocationRepository;

    public Block save(Block block) {
        return blockRepository.save(block);
    }

    public Allocation save(Allocation allocation) {
        return allocationRepository.save(allocation);
    }
}
```

**AllocationHandler.java**

```
    public List<Allocation> handleRequest(String input) {
        Block block = new Block();
        block.setQuantity(new BigDecimal(1000000));

        // Persist Block
        LOGGER.info("Persist block in DB");
        block = dbStore.save(block);
        LOGGER.info("Persisted Block in DB with Id [{}]", block.getBlockPk());

        Allocation allocation = new Allocation();
        allocation.setQuantity(new BigDecimal(500000));

        block.addAllocation(allocation);
        allocation.setBlock(block);

        LOGGER.info("Persist allocation in DB");
        allocation = dbStore.save(allocation);
        LOGGER.info("Persisted allocation in DB with Id [{}]", allocation.getAllocationPk());

        LOGGER.info("Update Block");
        block = dbStore.save(block);

        return Arrays.asList(allocation);
    }
```

There are two issues I am facing in the new application:

1. When I try to persist `Block` and then `Allocation` as shown in `AllocationHandler` class, `Block` gets persisted with a `unique auto-generated id` which is fine. But the same id is being used to persist `Allocation` as well instead of having a different auto-generated id based on the latest value in identity columns. I am sure there is no issue with Sybase DB and my version of SybDriver i.e. jconnect-7.0.GA because it already works as per the expectation in legacy application which uses lower version of this driver.
2. When I removed the dependency of `Block` from `Allocation` and tried to persist only the `Allocation`, I got following exception: "**Generated keys are not available because either the Statement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS was used or no keys were automatically generated Sybase.**". I am not sure why it worked for `Block` in step 1 but not working for `Allocation`.

Could someone please check and help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I was able to solve this issue.

Issue was with **couple of fields** that I was trying to persist. One of the **BigDecimal** fields had the precision issue and other was a **timestamp** field where format was not as per the column's expectation.

**Logs were enabled in TRACE mode for spring as well as hibernate, which were very misleading.**

In case of a successful as well as unsuccessful inserts, it was generating the similar kind of statements. Logs portrayed as if there was no issue with the data it is trying to insert and something wrong with Id column auto generation logic.

But finally, I constructed the insert query in an attempt to manually run the query against DB which obviously failed and helped me go in the right direction.